# DevStack placement-api did not start

Tags: python, openstack, devstack

I'm trying to install DevStack (stable/stein) in Ubuntu 18.04. I have installed python 3.6.8. I'm getting timeout issue and saying that placement-api did not start.

[image: DevStack console log]

[image: DevStack console log]

Is there any worker round for this ?

Comment: After getting the error I run ./unstack.sh and ./clean.sh. Now I'm getting g-api didn't start error.                                                                          
./stack.sh:1261:start_glance
/opt/stack/devstack/lib/glance:353:die
[ERROR] /opt/stack/devstack/lib/glance:353 g-api did not start
Error on exit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happen because of several runs of ./stack.sh and didn't clean the environment after using it. To overcome this problem we need to clean /etc/apache2/site-enable and /etc/apache2/site-available folders and run ./unstack.sh. After that we can run ./stack.sh

Thanks !